# Finding the current layout-xml file in focus using code

Tags: android, view, android-activity, polymorphism

I am working on a practice android project, and I am trying to implement polymorphism ideas into my program. So far, I have created two different XML layouts, one for tablets, and one for phones. They both have a button, but I want the button to do different things depending on which layout it is in. I am using the onClick property, and both layout's buttons refer to the same method.

In my buttonClick method, I want to find out which layout is is currently being shown, and I am trying to do it this way,

```
public void buttonClick(View ve)
{
    View v = getCurrentFocus();
            //According to the API, this method returns the current view, 
            //but the Log Tag says that it is null, which should not be the case. 

    Log.i(TAG, "Current View is " + v.getContentDescription());

            //I want to control what happens polymorphically using the next if-else 
            //clause,depending on the layout, I think that this part would work if
            //the above code works alright. 
    if(v.getId() == R.id.TabletLayout)
    {
        TextView myText = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView);
        if(myText.getText().toString().contains("World"))
            myText.setText(R.string.ayo_android);
        else
            myText.setText(R.string.hello_world);

        Log.i(TAG, "changing words");
    }
    else{

    Log.i(TAG, "Creating new Activity");
    myText = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView); 
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, NewActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra("screenText", myText.getText().toString());
    startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

That's not the way to do it.  If you want them to do different things, have the refer to different click handlers.  If they're widely different they shouldn't even have the same id.  The entire idea behind the automatic layout overrides is that the application should never need to care which one to use.

Comment: Yeah, but that's not very polymorphic. Having multiple methods solves the issue, but I want to do it in just one method.

Comment: No, its very polymorphic-  its polymorphic on the UI.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to [Gabe's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17336508/1369222), `getCurrentFocus()` will not give you the layout of the activity. If you want the layout of the activity, you can use

```
View v = (View)findViewById(android.R.id.content);
```